# Installed missing gems using bundler but still showing gem missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-2.7

using Rails ruby 2.7.2p137

I have installed the missing gem rake 13.03 but it is still showing missing gem.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-5-172:~/apps/tukaweb$ bundle install| grep rake
Using rake 13.0.3
ubuntu@ip-172-31-5-172:~/apps/tukaweb$ rails -v
Could not find rake-13.0.3 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command `gem install rake -v 13.0.3`and it should work.